# Insert backticks between string patterns

Tags: bash, shell

I have a requirement that I have to insert backticks in between certain string patterns, I have tried a couple of sed awk combinations to make it work but couldn't succeed.

Pattern: Multiple files with below content

```
 switch content;
 show content;
```

I want to read each file and convert the content as below:

```
switch `content`;
show content;
```

Whats the easiest/quickest way of doing this, thanks in advance.

Comment: *Showing* those `sed` and `awk` attempts, and how they failed, would make the question more concrete.

Comment: Would this not work? ``sed "s/content/`content`/g"``  -- For the sake of showing markdown .. I doubled the ticks up ..

Comment: @Zak, you can double up the *surrounding* backticks and leave the original ones unmodified. And no, it won't work with that invocation, as the shell will treat the backticks as syntax when they're given inside a double-quoted context, and thus will process them before they have a chance to get to `sed`.

Comment: @Zak Backticks perform command substitution inside double quotes. Use single quotes to process them literally. Also, your command will also modify `show content`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` with a capture group.

```
sed -i 's/switch \([^;]*\)/switch `\1`/' filenames...
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/3YuPU8)

Comment: thanks, though this produces output as :


     switch `contentA;`
     show contentA;

Instead of 

       switch `contentA`;
       show contentA;

Comment: I can't see the difference, since backtick has special meaning in comments.

Comment: I see, the `;` is inside the backticks. I've updated the answer to use `[^;]*` instead of `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
convert_re='[[:space:]]*switch[[:space:]](.*)[;]$[[:space:]]*'
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $convert_re ]]; then
    printf 'switch `%s`;\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done
```

...an invocation as:

```
./convert <<'EOF'
switch contentA;
show contentA;
switch contentB;
show contentB;
EOF
```

...yields as output:

```
switch `contentA`;
show contentA;
switch `contentB`;
show contentB;
```

...as you can see at https://ideone.com/Qq96f5